ADB и сброс телефона
Кто знает какими путями можно сбрасывать телефоны Samsung до заводских сохраняя ADB отладку?
ADB команда adb shell cmd testharness enable не подходит, так как на стоке телефон через н-ое кол во времени улетает в "Entering fastboot...".
Может быть есть какие то прошивки такие? или как собрать ее самому? или может есть волшебная команда которая все исправит?

Неужто есть те, кто про 4pda ничего не слыхали?
